# Writing a Checkbox Formula using 2 Picklist Fields

Tags: formula-field

I am having an issue writing a checkbox formula field on the Opportunity object.

I am trying to use 2 picklist fields - `Type` and `Stage`. I need the checkbox value to be true if

> Type = NULL, New Business, Paywall, or Reactivation AND Stage - Closed Won

Here is my formula:

```
IF
( ISPICKVAL(Type,"")|| 
ISPICKVAL(Type,"New Business")|| 
ISPICKVAL(Type,"Paywall")|| 
ISPICKVAL(Type,"Reactivation")&& 
ISPICKVAL(StageName,"Closed Won"),TRUE, FALSE)
```

The syntax check is showing no errors. My issue is that the checkbox is being marked TRUE for any StageName value instead of only Closed Won.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find a link to give the order of operations in a formula field, but I think `AND` has precedence over `OR`, so your formula is evaluating to:

> Type = NULL OR New Business OR Paywall OR (Reactivation AND Stage = Closed Won)

That means it will be TRUE when `Type` = "Reactivation" AND `Stage` = "Closed Won"; and it will also be TRUE when `Type` = NULL OR "New Business" OR "Paywall" *regardless* of what the `Stage` value is.

Surround your `Type` selections with parentheses to isolate them and separate them from the `StageName`...

```
IF
( (ISPICKVAL(Type,"") || 
   ISPICKVAL(Type,"New Business") || 
   ISPICKVAL(Type,"Paywall") || 
   ISPICKVAL(Type,"Reactivation") ) && 
   ISPICKVAL(StageName,"Closed Won")
,TRUE
,FALSE)
```

That should make your formula evaluate to:

> (Type = NULL OR New Business OR Paywall OR Reactivation) AND Stage = Closed Won

---

**Update**

To paraphrase what @DerekF said in his comment, the `IF()` is overkill, so you could use this:

```
( ISPICKVAL(Type,"") || 
  ISPICKVAL(Type,"New Business") || 
  ISPICKVAL(Type,"Paywall") || 
  ISPICKVAL(Type,"Reactivation") ) && 
ISPICKVAL(StageName,"Closed Won")
```

or, as I prefer to write it:

```
AND(
  OR(
    ISPICKVAL(Type,""),
    ISPICKVAL(Type,"New Business"),
    ISPICKVAL(Type,"Paywall"),
    ISPICKVAL(Type,"Reactivation")
  ),
  ISPICKVAL(StageName,"Closed Won")
)
```

Comment: Also, when you see something like `IF(<condition>, true, false)`, the `IF()` is unnecessary. The `<condition>` part already results in a boolean value. Similarly, `IF(<condition>, false, true)` can be reduced to `NOT(<condition>)`.

Comment: Thanks @DerekF : Deep down I *knew* that, but it is late and I was trying to answer this in the midst of other work, so I just modified the original formula and didn't think it all the way through. I appreciate you pointing that out, so I will edit my answer and add that.

Comment: It worked! You guys rock! THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU, SO MUCH! @DerekF

Comment: It worked! You guys rock! THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU, SO MUCH! @Moonpie

Comment: @ChristianBurnett Be sure to accept the answer that helped you the most. Upvoting is also encouraged, but you'll need 15 reputation score to do that. Accepting an answer gives you a bit of reputation, gives the person whose answer you accept a bit of reputation, and signals to the larger community that your problem is solved (and doesn't require more attention).